# Change Button icon on click play and pause

Tags: android, android-studio, button, icons

i want to add mp3 file to my app with play and pause button , currently i am using play and pause icon but i want to show play and pause button separately , like when user click on play button pause icon should show and vice versa , this is my code to play file

```java
Button play;
play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
            length = mp.getCurrentPosition();
        } else {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(PunjabiActivity.this, R.raw.japji);
            mp.seekTo((int) length);
            mp.start();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
play.setImageResource(R.drawable.playIcon);
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
            length = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseIcon)
        } else {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(PunjabiActivity.this, R.raw.japji);
            mp.seekTo((int) length);
            mp.start();
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.playIcon)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it is working but both icons are showing over the default icon, i mean the icon i have set in xml file not hiding

Comment: okay then don't set it in xml.
in acivity set icon programatically in oncreate() above onClickListener()

Comment: check updated answer for me its working i have done same way

Comment: it works :) can i change icon's size ? when i change it in xml not works

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your Button both in the layout and in the code with an ImageButton, then after calling mp.pause(); and mp.start(); you should respectively do:
`play.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourPlayIcon)` and `play.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourPauseIcon)`